# Huge number of events with event id 4625 win 2012 serrver

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2

I am receiving huge number of 4625 events in Win 2012 server. Below is the event details. Account name and the workstation name are the same and is the hostname of the machine in which I am receiving "An account failed to log on" events. Could someone please help me fix this.

```
Log Name:   Security
Source:     Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:        05/01/2017 6:47:08 AM
Event ID:   4625
Task Category: Logon
Level:       Information
Keywords:   Audit Failure
User:       N/A
Computer:   http://(ServerHostname).example.com

Description:
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
                Security ID:                       NULL SID
                Account Name:               -
                Account Domain:                           -
                Logon ID:                           0x0

Logon Type:                                     3


Account For Which Logon Failed:               Security ID:                       NULL SID
                Account Name:               ServerHostname
                Account Domain:                           example

Failure Information:
                Failure Reason:               Unknown user name or bad password.
                Status:                               0xC000006D
                Sub Status:                       0xC0000064

Process Information:
                Caller Process ID:           0x0
                Caller Process Name:   -

Network Information:
                Workstation Name:     ServerHostname
                Source Network Address:         ::1
                Source Port:                     50364

Detailed Authentication Information:
                Logon Process:               NtLmSsp
                Authentication Package:             NTLM
                Transited Services:       -
                Package Name (NTLM only):     -
                Key Length:                     0
```

Comment: From the events that i extracted for this server, I can see that the events 4625 and 4648 appear alternatively. The application name for 4648 will always be c:\windows\system32\tssdis.exe. I am suspecting this may be because of the server trying to authenticate the disconnected session. However, i am not sure about this.

Comment: Check all the comments in this post and see if any of these suggestions help you get it to stop (http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-4625-source-Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing-eventno-9984-phase-1.htm)